# charset issues with firefox on docker

Tags: debian, docker, container

My host is a Debian Buster build and i'm attempting to build a firefox-esr container (alpine base).  While i am able to bring up the brower using --net=host, i see an issue with charsets.

following is my host locale

```
LANG=en_IN
LANGUAGE=en_IN:en
LC_CTYPE="en_IN"
LC_NUMERIC="en_IN"
LC_TIME="en_IN"
LC_COLLATE="en_IN"
LC_MONETARY="en_IN"
LC_MESSAGES="en_IN"
LC_PAPER="en_IN"
LC_NAME="en_IN"
LC_ADDRESS="en_IN"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_IN"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_IN"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_IN"
LC_ALL=
```

i've set the following explicitly in my container

```
LANG=en_IN
LANGUAGE=en_IN:en
```

When the browser pops up.  the actual html pages seem to be fine (more or less :)) but the title bar and URL are completely messed up by what looks like a charset mismatch.

EDIT:  if i traverse a link, the whole web page turn into gibberish. added another screenshot.

i also see an error about a missing gtk library.  not sure how significant that is.

```
Gtk-Message: 08:42:07.455: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
```

any ideas on how i can fix this?  My host is gnome if that is important

this is what my browser looks like.  as you can, the html is fine except for input elements.  the actual browser pane is completely messed up.

[image: default page]

[image: another page]

[image: on traversal]

Answer (score 0):

I managed to sort this issue out.  I needed some additional packages for adwaita icons and dejavu fonts.  All good now!  I just looked around at other similar projects in docker hub and tried a few things and it worked out luckily.